# Eclipse search directories outside workspace?

Tags: eclipse, search, directory, workspace

I'm trying to search folders and files outside the workspace in Eclipse 3.0.2 on Windows 7.  These links helped:

http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/5-best-eclipse-plugins-system

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192767

Unfortunately I can only get Desktop Search to work, not System Search.  I've tried both the nokia system search download links:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=106032

http://www.steinerberg.com/EmbeddedComponents/System%20Search/com.nokia.search.system_2.0.0.201102171254.jar

I put either com.nokia.search.system or com.nokia.search.system_2.0.0.201102171254.jar in c:\eclipse-php\plugins.  I also tried putting com.nokia.search.system.feature in c:\eclipse-php\features but it still didn't work because the folder is empty so I get this message in eclipse's error log:

!MESSAGE Unable to find feature.xml in directory: C:\eclipse-php\features\com.nokia.search.system-feature

I take directory search for granted in tools like TextWrangler and Xcode on the Mac and am flabbergasted that the Eclipse developers don't include arbitrary file search in their IDE.

Another possibility is to somehow add the C drive to Eclipse's workspace.  I mainly need this to search directories like pear.  I guess a free app might be an ok solution, if there's a way to tie it into Eclipse somehow, that would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide,

Zack

Comment: Version 3.0.2 is pretty dated. Is there a reason for this requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understnad your question, you are trying to search folders/files outside of the eclipse workspace. My advice would be to create a new folder through new -> wizard select it as a "linked" folder and point it to the folder in your file system that you want to include in the search.

Say you want your C drive included in search. Create new folder, click on advanced which opens more otpions and select link to alternate location (linked folder) and click browse and select your c:\ drive. This will create folder in your workspace that is a pointer to the c drive and will be included in search queries.

Comment: Thank you, that worked extremely well.  I went to Eclipse->File->New->Other... then chose "Folder" from the list.  Click Next, then click Advanced, then choose "Link to alternate location (Linked Folder)" and select the folder you want to point at.  FYI I was worried how adding a folder would affect version control.  But these linked folders don't seem to affect SVN, so you can add them to a shared project without issue.  I gave you a point but will leave this question open for a while in case someone knows of a plugin.

Comment: If I write you a plugin will you accept the answer?! As far as I know for searching there are no IDE plugins that would search outside workspace resources because if they did, when you double click the search result how would it know where in navigator to put/display it.

Comment: I want to delete this linked folder as i have finished my searching and need not need it anymore. How can i do it

Comment: The entry is added in <linkedResources><link><name>app</name><type>2</type>location>D:/app</location></link></linkedResources> in .project file of eclipse project workspace. It can be deleted from there.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Duncan, thanks for your answer. It is the best for the purposes described in the original question.
I see this thread is a bit old but I would like to give some useful suggestions:

1. Additional plugins only slow down Eclipse. It already has so many plug-ins that come with it. I try to keep mine as slim as possible (a lean version of STS) and use external tools for tasks I perform outside of core development, like version control - I removed all my Git and SVN plug-ins manually.
2. Linked folders work best because you narrow down the search. If you try to search the entire file system you are probably better off using your OS and its built-in utilities designed specifically for that. They are faster and support all sort of searches that you would otherwise not be able to execute from Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this on 3.0.2 but I came across this question after trying to setup a new Eclipse and working out which plugin I had before that allowed me to do this.

Turns out you need RSE (Remote System Explorer) which gives you Remote Search and you can use a local connection to select a folder on your local machine.